# Can object detection approaches be used to solve text/detection problems?

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, object-recognition, text-detection

I have been working on text detection and recognition for almost two months and new on this field. So far, I have fine-tuned, tested, and trained several text detection/recognition methods, such as **CRAFT**, **TextFuseNet**, **CharNet** for detection, and [**clova.ai**](https://github.com/clovaai/deep-text-recognition-benchmark) model for recognition. Now I come up with this question:

- Can object detection approaches(yolov5,efficientDet) be used to solve text/detection problems?

Comment: Hello. Let me try to understand if I understood your concerns/problem. You have used **text** detection methods for **text** detection. Now, you want to use **object** detection methods for **text** detection. You're asking if that will work? If this is correct, why do you want to use object detection methods/models for text detection?

Comment: Hello. It's a suggestion from my supervisor, and now I am stuck with these ideas. I wanted to know if there is someone already experienced this kind of task.

Comment: Ok, then rather than asking "Is object detection right way for text detection/recognition?", it would be better to ask "can object detection approaches be used to solve text/detection problems?".